# C# Serial Port not reading correctly when using Semaphore to wait for answer

Tags: c#, semaphore

first up, I'm running C# in MS Visual Community 2015.
Following problem:

I have a stepper motor that is connected to a controlboard. This board accepts 9-byte array commands send to it via USB conection. I send those commands via SerialPort in C#. Each byte has a certain meaning (board number, motor number, command number, 0-byte, 4 bytes for the value in hex bytes, checksum)

EVERY command send makes the board fire a 9-byte array answer which I catch in a DataReceived Handle.

In the programm, when the user pushes a button, I want folling executed:

1. Motor starts rotation (special command)
2. Programm registers other input from a pressure sensor
3. Motor stops turning (special command)
4. Position of motor is saved. (command "request positon" is send, the answer contains the position, the 4 byte value mentioned earlier)

Now, as I send mutiple commands on a single button push, and i read that DataReceived starts a new thread, i came across the solution of using semaphores to wait until my DataReceive Handle has collected the complete answer. I also have all Methods on seperate buttons for testing.

The problem now is that If i run everything on a single button push my position varies always by around 130-140 steps to the actual postion (which i get from the single button test).

Here is the the extract from the program:

```
 class Motor
{
    public static readonly Motor Instance = new Motor();
    USBSerialTest.Motorsbefehle MB = new Motorsbefehle();
    byte[] PermaSave = new byte[9];
    byte[] buf = new byte[9];
    Semaphore _sync = new Semaphore(0, 1);

    private Motor()
    {
        MotorPort = new SerialPort();
        MotorPort.PortName = "COM6";
        MotorPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
        MotorPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 9;
        MotorPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(dataRecievedHandler);
        MotorPort.Open();
    }

    private void dataRecievedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        int bytes = MotorPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        buf = buffer;
        _sync.Release();
    }

    public SerialPort MotorPort { get; private set; }

    public void StartRotate(string speed)
    {
        var commandBytes = MB.TMCL_RMR(speed);
        MotorPort.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);
        _sync.WaitOne();
    }

    public void StopRotate()
    {
        var commandBytes = MB.TMCL_MST();
        MotorPort.Write(commandBytes, 0, commandBytes.Length);
        _sync.WaitOne();

    }

    public void RequestPosition()
    {
        var commandbytes = MB.GET_POSI();
        MotorPort.Write(commandbytes, 0, commandbytes.Length);
        _sync.WaitOne();
    }

    public string SavePosition()
    {
        PermaSave = buf;
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(buf);
        hex.Replace(",", "-");
        return hex;
    }
```

Example of how the byte array looks (this would be the stop motor command)

```
    public byte[] TMCL_MST()
    {
        return new byte[] { 0x1, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4 };          
    }
```

I call it in my Form like this:

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string speed = textBox4.Text;
        Motor.Instance.StartRotate(speed);

        keyance2.SendCommand();
        decimal caliber = keyance2.GetDecimalOutput();
        decimal actualValue = 0;
        do
        {
            keyance2.SendCommand();
            actualValue = keyance2.GetDecimalOutput();
        }
        while (actualValue <= caliber);

        Motor.Instance.StopRotate();
        Motor.Instance.RequestPosition();
        string hex = Motor.Instance.SavePosition();
        textBox5.Text = hex;
    }
```

As said, this one button push solution produces a result that is different from what I get when doing `Motor.Instance.RequestPosition();` and `Motor.Instance.SavePosition();` both on a seperate button push after the motor stopped turning (the value I get here is identical with what I get from the board producer software, so the correct value). Not by much and I wonder where my error might be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be more precice, after I click button_13 and textBox5 displays my position I recheck. I press a button which activates `Motor.Instance.RequestPosition();` and then i press a button which activates `Motor.Instance.SavePosition();` and then displays the result again. On a few tests so far where I compared the values there was always a difference of around 130, sometimes more sometimes less.

Comment: You are making this unnecessarily difficult.  There is just no benefit to using the DataReceived event handler at all since the semaphore is going to block your UI thread anyway.  Keep it simple and make it synchronous.  Most likely flaw is that the StopRotate() command only tells the controller to stop motion but does not wait until the motor decelerates to 0 speed.  So the position you read is obtained too early.  Note how StartRotate() avoids that, you loop until you are happy.  You could do that for stopping as well.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the input. With the controller reading to early makes sense. Synchronus means having a `Motorport.ReadByte()` after each send command seperatley (or within an extra method) ? Is it a big difference in efficieny doing it the way I'm currently doing and doing it the way you suggested?